# Getting error: Must specify an `id` when calling `Model.room(id)` with Sails.js Pub/Sub

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to use pub/sub methods and I get spammed with this error:

```
error: Must specify an `id` when calling `Model.room(id)`
```

My Model looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

  tableName: 'accounts',
  autoPk: false,

  attributes: {
    'id': {
      type: 'INTEGER',
      primaryKey: true,
      columnName: 'id'
    },

    'alias': {
      type: 'STRING',
      required: true
    }
};
```

and then my controller method:

```
'subscribe': function(req, res) {
        Account.find({'select': ['steam_id', 'online']})
        .then(function(users) {
            Account.subscribe(req.socket, users);   
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

and finally, my client-side js subscribe:

```
socket.on('connect', function connectedToSockets() {
    console.log('Subscribing');
    socket.get('/friends/subscribe');
    socket.get('/user/subscribe');
  });
```

I cannot for the life of me, figure out why I am getting literally spammed by this error, all the fixes say to set a PrimaryKey on a column,

I'm using `sails-mysql` adapter

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So to anybody that has this problem, I figured it out:

I wasn't returning the ID from the query under subscribing, so when I added ID as well the error goes away, I guess it just need the ID for some reference.

```
'subscribe': function(req, res) {
        Account.find({'select': ['id', 'steam_id', 'online']})
        .then(function(users) {
            Account.subscribe(req.socket, users);   
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

This fixed it, adding id

Comment: You can validate your answer I suppose :-)